# iOS Are you sure dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a lot of UIAlertViews and now I just want a self contained Class which displays a UIAlertView with a Yes/No button. This is my idea in code:

```
[DXPopUp areYouSure:@"SOME MESSAGE HERE" callback:^( BOOL isSure ) {
    ... do something ...
}];
```

The problem with this approach is the delegate inside DXPopUp:

```
- ( void ) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Is never called because a self reference is already gone, which I understand. So I fixed this by making it a method instead of class method and create a strong reference inside the calling class.

But I am wondering if my first idea can be accomplished because I feel this is much cleaner?

Comment: I had a similar question earlier and received some pretty good answers (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669566/how-to-access-user-input-from-uialertview-completion-block-without-delegation). Also in iOS8+ you can just use the built-in UIAlertController which uses closures quite nicely.

Comment: Two questions: how do you initialize the UIAlertView and what is used to delegate it ? In short: please add more related code.

Comment: Use UIAlertController.....it uses blocks by default with UIActions. No delegate required. Besides, UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this creating a category on UIAlertView and by using associated objects on the category: [Associated Objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/)

See this library for creating UIAlertViews with blocks.

[UIAlertView+Blocks](https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIAlertView-Blocks)

Comment: Thank you! I feel so stupid since I should know this ;)!